# My CSS is not importing from another directory

Tags: html

So I'm trying to import a CSS stylesheet from JavaScript, and my HTML file is in JavaScript/JavaScript events, so I did this.

```
<Head>
    <title>Javascript</title>
    <link href="../styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
</Head>
<body>
```

`../` is meant to go back and then to the styles.css file. But when I open a live server to see if the styles are working, they are not showing up.

Here is my CSS code:

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: rgb(119, 114, 114)
}

ul .done {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

Comment: Did you check your dev tools console and network tabs for errors? Have you cleared your cache?

Comment: Can you update your post with a screenshot of your file structure?

Comment: why you use head with capital H?

Comment: @CharlesBarnes One is required to post such things as text, not screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

Alwais use absolute path like: https://somedomain.com/style.css

or relative path beginnig slash like: /style.css

then browser will always find correct file path.